# How to confirm a file is in use after it attempted to delete?

Tags: javascript, file-io

Is there a way to know a file is in use, **after** attempting it to delete?

The [DeleteFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thx0f315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't return any value to verify such scenario. is there any alternative that can be used to validate "an error message is thrown", if I tried to delete a file in use?

Comment: You could always check whether or not it exists after attempted deletion.

Comment: no.. The file exists. I want to validate whether or not the file is in use.. if it is in use, the attempted deletion should throw an error which I have to capture

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no explicit method in .NET.

You can, however, open and close the file with exclusive permissions and catch the error:

```
Public Function IsFileInUse(ByVal myFile As String) As Boolean
    If File.Exists(myFile) Then
        Try
            Dim hnd As Short = FreeFile()
            FileOpen(hnd, myFile, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.LockReadWrite)
            FileClose(hnd)
        Catch
            Return True
        End Try
    End If
End Function
```

Don't know what you are using (or what this has to do with javascript), so I posted this example *without testing* in VB.NET.